# How to read/write partitioned Apache Arrow or Parquet files into/out of Julia

Tags: julia, parquet, apache-arrow

I am trying to read and write a trivial dataset into Julia. The dataset is `mtcars`, taken from R, with an arbitrarily added column `bt` with random Boolean values. The file/folder structure (below) was written out using the R `arrow` package.

The files are laid out as follows:

```
arr
|-- bt=false
|   `-- part-1.arrow
`-- bt=true
    `-- part-0.arrow
```

How can I faithfully reproduce the original table in Julia?

What I've tried so far:

1. Using the `Parquet.jl` package. Documentation suggests that it should automatically detect partitioning folder structure for columns of bool/string/date type. When I read the data in, using `read_parquet(path; kwargs)`, the resulting data structure does not have the `bt` column. I've tried setting the `column_generator` keyword argument to the default `Parquet.dataset_column_generator` but this did not work.
2. Using `Arrow.jl` - I cannot find a documented way (unless I misunderstood) to directly read in a partitioned data structure.

R does not generate additional metadata files to store the schema, but I understand this is optional and not part of the arrow spec?

Comment: Unfortunately your best bet might be using `Pycall` to use the python parquet reader to read this file correctly

Comment: That is unfortunate; I will give it a try nonetheless. Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide link to download this dataset? It would help with trying out what works and what does not.

Comment: Thanks. This is the dataset in Arrow format: https://send.vis.ee/download/18cb5247bc34f898/#ZXfAhzog1OIeX4XhZit22Q

Comment: There is an issue open for this at Parquet.jl: https://github.com/JuliaIO/Parquet.jl/issues/154

Answer (score 1):

Try this. They have listed a method as this

Partitions in a parquet file or dataset can also be iterated over using an iterator returned by the `Tables.partitions` method.

```
using Parquet, DataFrames
for partition in Tables.partitions(read_parquet(path))
    df = DataFrame(partition)
    ...
end
```

For further reference: https://github.com/JuliaIO/Parquet.jl